# jQuery change matched text

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to change text where td value is: `"null"` to `"Not rating found"`!. But it keep changing all values instead only matched ones.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".form-inline").submit(doStuff);
});

function doStuff(e){
e.preventDefault();

var input = $("#nanizankaInput").val();
var link = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=";
link = link + input; 

$.ajax({
    url: link,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

var prazno = $("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text();

   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     $("thead").first().append( "<tr>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.id + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.rating.average + "</td>" +"</tr>");

     if ($("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text("null")) {
       $("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text("No rating found!")
     }
   }
}});
}
```

You have to input something like `"bad"` to see result.

> Live Demo: http://jsbin.com/dupuzonita/edit?html,js,output

Comment: `if ($("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text("null")) {` you are setting the text to `null` here, but you want to compare: `if ($("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text() === "null") {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a rating class and trick worked. Check and try out the below code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".form-inline").submit(doStuff);
});

function doStuff(e){
e.preventDefault();

var input = $("#nanizankaInput").val();
var link = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=";
link = link + input; 

$.ajax({
    url: link,
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

var prazno = $("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text();

   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    $("thead").first().append( "<tr>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.id + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.name + "</td>" + "<td class='rating'>" + data[i].show.rating.average + "</td>" +"</tr>");

   }
     $(".rating").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() == 'null')
          $(this).text('No rating found!');
     });
}});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition check is wrong

```
if ($("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text("null")) {
       $("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text("No rating found!")
}
```

You are setting the value instead of checking it so evertime it returns true in `$(selector).text("null")`

```
if ($("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text() === "null") {
       $("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text("No rating found!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from text mistake, you are looping through rows but checking 3rd td of first row only.

You need to change the code like below.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $(".form-inline").submit(doStuff);
});

function doStuff(e){
e.preventDefault();

var input = $("#nanizankaInput").val();
var link = "http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=";
link = link + input; 

$.ajax({
url: link,
method: 'GET',
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);

var prazno = $("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text();

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
 $("thead").first().append( "<tr>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.id + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + data[i].show.rating.average + "</td>" +"</tr>");
 var td = $("thead tr").eq(i).find("td:nth-child(3)");
 if (td.html() === "null") {
   td.html("No rating found!")
 }
}
}});
}
```

You can also use nth-child selector like you have used for td.

```
$("thead tr:nth-child("+i+") td:nth-child(3)");
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace to

```
if ( !$("thead tr td:nth-child(3)").text() )
```